# Как загрузить нескольких файлов в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Как прописать в контролере загрузку не скольких файлов из формы.
Сейчас у меня грузит один. Я пробовала указывать на форме где name="file_task[]" и в контроллере использовать метод store(), он передаю массив, но вот путь передает неправильный .
Контроллер для загрузки одного файла:

```
    class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(StoreRequest $request)
    {

        $data = $request->validated();

        // указываем куда перемещаем файл
        $data['file_task'] = Storage::disk('public')->put('/images', $data['file_task']);

       Task::firstOrCreate($data);


        return redirect()->route('operator.task.index');
    }

}
```

и форма

```
                        <div class="form-group class = w-50">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">Добавить файл</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="file_task[]" multiple class="custom-file-input">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label">Выберите файл</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">Загрузка</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: попробуйте проверить что у вас лежит в $data['file_task'], скорее всего там должен быть массив по которому нужно пройтись и сохранить каждый файл отдельно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте что-то вроде этого:

```
foreach ($request->file('file_task') ?? [] as $file) {
    // save each file
}
```